# Redshift SUPER type: accessing camel case fields returning null result

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to access fields of a SUPER column which have camel case fields, so something like:

```
{"FirstName": "Mario", "LastName": "Maria"}
```

So let's say I store this field in Redshift as column `my_json`, then I'd query it with

```
SELECT my_json.FirstName
FROM my_table
```

Then I'd get only `null` result instead of the real value.

How to handle this use case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Second Redshift defaults to lower case for all column names so FirstName is being seen as firstname. You can enable case sensitive column names by setting the `enable_case_sensitive_identifier` connection variable to true and quoting all column names that require upper characters:

```
SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true;
```

and changing `my_json.FirstName` to `my_json."FirstName"`.

See:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_enable_case_sensitive_identifier.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/super-configurations.html

Comment: that is working for me, thanks! Hope other users will find it useful as well. Are you aware of any unexpected side effects about enabling this variable?

Comment: Yes.  Most BI tools expect some level of case insensitivity so be careful in which sessions you enable this option.  If your BI tools need this option to access the correct data you may need to do some work-arounds (but many work fine).  Same for some ETL tools.  SQL writes often assume that case doesn't matter so some existing SQL may need to be fixed.  Etc.

Answer (score 1):

adding to @Bill's answer above, there is a less general flag you can enable for `SUPER` json fields.

In your case, you can enable enable_case_sensitive_super_attribute  like so:

```
SET enable_case_sensitive_super_attribute to TRUE;
 -- Accessing JSON attribute names with uppercase and mixedcase names
```

For your case, this is better than `enable_case_sensitive_identifier`, since that flag affects databases, tables, columns, etc.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/super-configurations.html

Answer (score 0):

`SET enable_case_sensitive_super_attribute to TRUE;`
Was not enough in my case. I also had to quote the identifier in the select statement:
`SELECT mycolumn."Myfield" FROM mytable`